# Open windows camera on file input html5

Tags: html

Using HTML5 and a standard input tag it is clear we can open the cmera app on any Android and IoS devices.  But how on earth do we access the same on a Windows device.

I am not trying to stream the image and create a snapshot using a canvas, all I want to do is give a windows user the same 'Take Picture' option as every other device seems tto offer.

Many thanks for all comments in advance